# npm install imagemagick-native not getting installed in Windows 7

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, node-imagemagick

npm install imagemagick-native is not getting installed. 
1. Issue 1 - Not able to find lib files
2. Issue 2 - Failed on finding X11.lib.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Issue 1** - I didn't install the included libraries and dependencies while installing imagemagick(ImageMagick-6.9.1-5-Q8-x64-dll.exe). After reinstalling with additional dependencies selected during installation process solves this issue.

**Solution for Issue 2** - Removed *'-l<(MAGICK_ROOT)/lib/X11.lib'* from *binding.gyp*. Run *node-gyp configure, node-gyp build* solved the issue.

Tip : Either you can get source of imagemagic-native from github (https://github.com/mash/node-imagemagick-native) or terminate process after giving npm install imagemagick-native before it fails.